# Can I enable Azure Cosmos DB free tier multiple times (one at a time)?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I know that "There’s a maximum of one free tier account per Azure subscription", but does it mean maximum one at a time or maximum one in total? In case of the first option, if I deleted the account for which I had enabled free tier, I would be able to use when I create a new one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> but does it mean maximum one at a time or maximum one in total?

It is maximum one at a time. You can delete a free tier account and create another one targeting the same or different API. For example, you can first create a free tier account targeting SQL API, delete it and create another free tier account targeting SQL API or Gremlin (or any other API).